# Semantic UI Searchable Dropdown Default Value with API is overwritten

Tags: asp.net-mvc, semantic-ui

In a .net MVC app, trying to learn semantic UI. (2.2.13) I've been beating my head against the wall on this one.
I have a remote populated dropdown, that I'm trying to create a default value for at initial page load.
The API is working, returning expected data.

My problem is that when a user 'tabs' into the element, the forceSelection default of the apiSettings forces the selection of the first item in the dropdown, which in this case is not what my default value is.  (In this case, say that CAT is the first option in the list)

The desired behavior is keeping 'DOG' as the selected value when tabbed through, and i would like to keep the functionality of 'forceSelection' to prevent a user from leaving the dropdown with something typed that isn't included in the dropdown options.

I'm THINKING that i need a way of passing the current (default) value, and making that the selected value when the dropdown is initialized?

Here's the .js, in a doc ready.

```
  $('.quom').dropdown({
        apiSettings: {
            url: 'ActualUrlRemoved',
            cache: false
        },
        fields: {
            name: 'Animal_Name',
            value: 'Animal_Name'
        },
        onShow: function (val) {
            ///set active based on val here??
           // $(this).val('DOG');
        }

    });
```

And the HTML setting the default 'DOG' (and using the "" value as the label) :

```
  <select id="animalTest" name="ANIMAL" class="ui fluid search selection dropdown quom">
                                        <option value="">Animal*</option>
                                       <option value="DOG" selected>DOG</option>
                                    </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. This works for me.

```
    $('.quom').dropdown({
    apiSettings: {
        url: 'URLHERE',
        cache: false
    },
    fields: {
        name: 'Animal_Name',
        value: 'Animal_Name'
    },
    onShow: function () {            
        current = $(this).val();
        $(this).dropdown('set selected', current);

    }

});
```